# Quickly toggle between left- and right-handed mouse settings

Tags: windows, mouse

I use the mouse in its left-handed setting, on Windows. However, I often have to collaborate hands-on with someone else in my computer, and I'd prefer to use the right-handed setting in those occasions.

Going trough the Control Panel, finding the correct item, and then performing the change is a quite tedious routine.

**Is there an instantaneous way (graphical or not) to toggle said setting?**

Comment: Buy a Logitech G300.  They can support 3 different profiles. Each profile can have buttons assigned to mean anything you want.  Switch between profiles by using the mode button.

Answer (score 0):

By installing [IntelliType](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26950), then by pressing this keyboard combination:

> Windows Logo+I: Opens Mouse Properties dialog box

This above procedure can only be done if you have a Microsoft Keyboard.

Here is a [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126449) to all the keyboard and mouse shortcuts for Microsoft.